# Event Receiver Error Message in Word

Tags: 2013, event-receivers

I have created an Event Receiver for ensuring users enter comments when checking in a document. It works fine when the user checks in the document in Sharepoint but if the user tries to check in the document in a MS Office application ie Word, it returns the following error message:

"We can't do that for you because the file is no longer checked out or has been deleted."

How can I get Word to display the correct error message.  The code I am using for the Event Receiver is as follows:

```
public override void ItemCheckingIn(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    base.ItemCheckingIn(properties);
    SPListItem item = properties.ListItem;
    //if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.File.CheckInComment))
    string comment = (string)properties.AfterProperties["vti_sourcecontrolcheckincomment"];
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(comment))

    {

        properties.ErrorMessage = "You must add comments when you check in a file";
        properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithError;
    }

}
```

Thanks